# How to add browse button to glyphicon-picture in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

In my page I have a text area and it has glyphicon-picture's button and glyphicon-video's button, now I need to add browse button to these buttons, how can I do this?

Edit:

```
<table cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="5px" style="margin: auto; margin-top: 10px">
  <tr>
    <td class="design"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="font-size: 18px;"></span></td>
    <td class="design"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture design-icon"></span></td>
    <td class="design"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video design-icon"></span></td>
    <td class="design"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link design-icon"></span></td>
    <td class="design"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar design-icon"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

now I just have this and I want to add browse button to `glyphicon-picture` and I dont know how do this.

Comment: Please share your code and what you've tried.

Comment: @MrUpsidown : please check edit.tnx.

Comment: The answer from @Joseph seems correct. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add glyphicon image to a button ..Try the following code.Hope it helps

```
 <button class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i>Elham Gdz</button>
```